# K8s How to deploy pod 1 per specific node, not all node in cluster

Tags: kubernetes

Let say I have a cluster with 10 worker nodes and the application is randomly deployed to them. I have a namespace X, have 20 instances of nodejs that want to connect to MySQL Group Replication via MySQL Router.
I want to deploy 1 instance of MySQL Router to every node that has at least 1 of my nodejs application. Is this logic support with the k8s default rule?
Ex:

- node1: 4 nodejs, 1 router
- node2: 3 nodejs, 1 router
- node3: 12 nodejs, 1 router
- node4: 1 nodejs, 1 router
- other nodes: no app => no router

[image]

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/

Comment: @ĐinhAnhHuy Does the above source solve your issue?

Comment: I don't think so. I find the answer "Inter-pod affinity": "this pod should (or, in the case of anti-affinity, should not) run in an X if that X is already running one or more pods that meet rule Y".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Inter-pod affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity):

> this pod should (or, in the case of anti-affinity, should not) run in an X if that X is already running one or more pods that meet rule Y.